# How to access Web api using token from windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

My windows form application code is given below, it is just calling web api using token.

```
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:123456/");                            
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " +  Constants.SetAccessToken);                                                                   
                        var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<string>("Account", output);
                        responseTask.Wait();

                        var result = responseTask.Result;
                        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {

                        }
                    }
```

My web api controller function is given below for save data,

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    
    public ActionResult<string> SaveData([FromBody] string Data)
    {
        var user = this.User.Claims.Last().Value;
        

        Db.ExecuteStoredProcedureJsonData(Data);
        
        return "Data Saved";

    }
```

Authentication Controller function is given below for authenticating with google(gmail) credentials,

```
    [Route("google-login")]
    public ActionResult GoogleLogin()
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse") };
        return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [Route("google-response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var claims = result.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()
            .Claims.Select(claim => new
            {
                claim.Issuer,
                claim.OriginalIssuer,
                claim.Type,
                claim.Value
            });
        
        return Ok(claims);
    }
```

Startup.cs class is given below

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           
        })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                
                options.LoginPath = "/account/google-login"; 
               
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
               
                options.ClientId = "1234ClientId";

                options.ClientSecret = "abcdSecret";
            });
   }
```

I am login with google authentication in windows form & gets token of google authentication. When i run windows application with bearer token, it hits web api, it goes to GoogleLogin() function only & return 200 with success message. it does not goes to SaveData() function of Account Controller. What is the solution.

Comment: If your request goes to GoogleLogin, it means that request was unauthorized/unauthenticated. What is missing in provided example is how authentication is configured for the API and how you retrieve token in Win app

Comment: Google authentication in api. ie; in my start up class in web api, options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    
                    options.LoginPath = "/account/google-login"; // Must be lowercase
                   
                })
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                   
                    options.ClientId = "1234ClientId";

                    options.ClientSecret = "abcdSecret";
                });

Comment: Can you check my question once more, i have included start up class. i am using google authentication in web api. My reference link https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-google-authentication-to-a-asp-net-core-application

Comment: The same client id , Client secret used in both windows form & web api

Comment: Right now your API configured to use Cookie authentication. But u need to use .AddJwtBearer(options => {}), also you don't need AddGoogle in you web api, token verification parameters should be configured in JwtBearer options